# How to communicate between via wifi iOS and android?

Tags: android, ios, bluetooth, wifi

i need to communicate between ios and android.i think ios's bluetooth is not support bluetooth communication.so i chose wifi.is there any way to communicatiton?

AIM:I need to send and recive json datas between this.Any idea?

Comment: one way you can make this happen is by running the same application on both devices…If you could expound on your exact purpose people would find it easier to answer.

Comment: but i am doubt about the communication chanel..i need to send and recive json datas.actualy bluetooth is the easier way.but ios not support bluetooth communication with non-ios devices.

Comment: Your only way is through wifi and based on the actual purpose you can find an optimal solution. Can you explain what are u trying to achieve here by transferring ?

Answer (score 1):

Look for AsyncSocket (http://code.google.com/p/cocoaasyncsocket/) for iOS and java.net.ServerSocket/java.net.Socket for Android.

Comment: that link is broken.

Comment: Well, now is SwiftSocket is more relevant: https://github.com/swiftsocket/SwiftSocket